# CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I make a backup of some database from distance server, and I had an problem on my local server when I trying to import that backup. I get an error in this line:

`CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@% SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW tematics_field AS select....`.

Both server have a mysql 5.5.2x. And users are different in that two servers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to put the hostname (or wildcard in this case) in single-quotes:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@'%' SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW tematics_field AS 
select.....
```

Comment: what is the different bewin "CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@'%' SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW" and simple "CREATE VIEW"?

Comment: All those extra clauses are optional, you can read about them here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html

Comment: @mrakodol, in MySQL, '%' matches any IP address or hostname, but not localhost.  Localhost uses the UNIX socket instead of TCP/IP.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-names.html

Answer (score 19):

I only try to:

```
CREATE VIEW tematics_field AS select....
```

And all is work perfectly and import is well done.

Answer (score 18):

MySql Error: #1227 – Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS SELECT DISTINCT `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` FROM (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` JOIN `decg_catalog_product_entity` `product` ON(`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)) ;
```

**Fixed Solution:**

The problem is you set definer as root, which is not your current running user, that’s why you need to **SUPER privilege**.
you can create a user called root in RDS, and use root to run the command, or simply

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```

change to:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=CURRENT_USER SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```

read more about CURRENT_USER
Final SQL query looks like

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=CURRENT_USER SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS SELECT DISTINCT `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` FROM (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` JOIN `decg_catalog_product_entity` `product` ON(`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)) ;
```

Thank you.From: [MazziTorch](https://www.mazzitorch.com/import-failure-create-algorithm-1227/)

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar thing. In place of :

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`cccts_org`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW
```

I substituted CURRENT_USER() for the DEFINER and it worked.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=CURRENT_USER() SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW
```

If that is used in the next import, it should be portable and not trip over the old credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@% SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW tematics_field AS select.....
Please remove "ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@% SQL SECURITY DEFINER" and keep like "CREATE VIEW tematics_field AS select.....
it will work while importing or direct pasting under sql tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Error messages:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line XXXX: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Just try this:

```bash
sed -i.bak 's/`root`@`%`/CURRENT_USER/g' /path/to/your.sql
```

> Note: '`root`@`%`' is the user who defined that view.

or edit sql file in VIM:

```
:%s/`root`@`%`/CURRENT_USER/g
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=CURRENT_USER SQL SECURITY INVOKER

Answer (score 0):

### In my case, no varinate helped me and I decided to remove this part completely:

"-- Structure for view 'new_view' "

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'new_view'; CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER='root'@'localhost' SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW 'new_view'  AS SELECT .....;`

And it completely helped to solve the error,  and **new_view was saved**