# Duplicate Laravel web app to subdomain and separate the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a web app built using Laravel and MySQL. It's currently running on my www.domain.com

I would like to know how to *"duplicate"* the web app to a subdomain with a separated database?

The web app has login and signup features. There's also email notification sent to clients if they sign up, make changes, etc.

The reason I'm doing this is because I have two types of clients, local and overseas clients. Therefore I have to separate them since they use different currencies and languages. So, when my team login to the subdomain, they'll know they have to speak in our local language, but when they login to the www.domain.com, they'll know they have to speak English.

Thanks very much, will appreciate any help

**UPDATE** The database has been successfully copied to a new database, however the sign up and login pages of the subdomain are linked to the main domain.

Comment: Duplicating your app and setting it up with a new [.env](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example) file might be a good place to start. Then creating new database and database user, re-running migrations, seeders, etc.

Comment: What I've tried: modified the currency on localhost and uploaded it to the subdomain directory. I then created the database and assigned a user from cpanel. After that, I used the same database and modified the name and user based on the newly created. But when uploaded through phpmyadmin, I got an error. Can it be done this way? Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier from a record keeping point of view to just keep track of language and currency inside the original app, rather than duplicating it and making your employees have to switch between systems?

Comment: Try asking the original developer to set up a second instance for you :)

Comment: @LucasKrupinski Thank you Lucas that's true, however from our side it will be easier if we separate the app and its database

Comment: @LucasKrupinski Thank you Lucas have done that :) We've spent a lot in the development and the developer asked for the same price to set it up which we couldn't afford. So, we're actually trying to figure things out by ourselves (we hope it's possible).

Answer (score 0):

You could look up https://hyn.readme.io which does pretty much exactly what you want. It lets you setup new tenants which are assigned a subdomain and creates a separate database while at the same time sharing your actual application between them all.

If needed you can add tenant-specific overrides of the default apps views and whatnot by adding them to the tenants own folders.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment earlier, you are getting error in phpMyAdmin when trying to upload database. Why not just copy the database in phpMyAdmin? Go to database you want click on **Operations** then under Copy Database type name of new database and select copy structure and data. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Ok. So what is the exact error message you are getting on phpMyAdmin? Can you please share screenshot or something?

Comment: Sure, this is the error after copying the database in phpmyadmin [link](http://imgur.com/a/Y9374)

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600564/create-algorithm-undefined-definer[/link]